# Using folder in Multi media picker

Tags: c#, umbraco

I want to be able to select a folder in de media picker and display the images inside the folder on my page.

I am able to get the folder, but not to get the images out of the folder. As you can see in the code below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MediaGallary)
        {
            if (item.DocumentTypeAlias != "Folder")
            {
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                    <a style="overflow-x:hidden; height:100%" href="@item.Url" data-lightbox="example-set" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="@item.GetCropUrl("gallaryThumbnail")+@count" />
                        <p>@item.Name</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                { count++; }
            } else
            {

            }
        }
```

I'm looking for a explanationon for how i can get the image out of the folder inside the else function.

**SOLUTION**

To solve my issue all i had to do was add a foreach loop to get the child items.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.MediaGallary)
        {
            if (item.DocumentTypeAlias != "Folder")
            {
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                    <a style="overflow-x:hidden; height:100%" href="@item.Url" data-lightbox="example-set" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="@item.GetCropUrl("gallaryThumbnail")+@count" />
                        <p>@item.Name</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                { count++; }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var mediaItem in item.Children)
                {
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                        <a style="overflow-x:hidden; height:100%" href="@mediaItem.Url" data-lightbox="example-set" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="@mediaItem.GetCropUrl("gallaryThumbnail")+@count" />
                            <p>@mediaItem.Name</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    { count++; }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, assuming item is an `IPublishedContent` you could do the following:

```cs
var media = item.Children;
```

You could go further and try this (assuming you're using Models generated with ModelsBuilder in Umbraco 7):

```cs
var images = item.Children<Image>();
```

Comment: Sorry i did not include more information. Wanted to have this question out before i had to leave. so had to write it up quick. I will try your answer tonight. Looks promising

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It pushed me in the right direction